# Getting fetch is undefined in internet explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am coming to an issue where my code below, says that `'fetch' is undefined` in internet explorer 11. I am using the latest jquery which is `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` and I even tried `$.ajax` instead of `fetch` but that did not work. Can anyone help me solve this issue, with my code below. That it can even work in ie11. thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";

$(function () {
    var myData = [];


    $.get("#{request.contextPath}/JobSearchItem.xhtml", function (data) {

        $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: myData,
            select: function select(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
                var searchValue = ui.item.value;
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
                fetch(url, {
                    body: data,
                    method: "post"
                }).then(function (res) {
                    return res.text();
                }).then(function (text) {
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
                    $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
                    $("#clearone").show();
                });
            },
            response: function response(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.content.length) {
                    var message = { value: "", label: "NO SEARCH RESULT FOUND" };
                    ui.content.push(message);
                }
            }

        });


        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            myData.push({
                id: v.id,
                label: v.label,
                value: v.id

            });
        });
    });


    $("#sJobClass").change(function () {
        var jobClassCd = $(this).val();
        if (jobClassCd !== 0) {
            var url = '#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml';
            var searchValue = $('#sJobClass').val();
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('searchValue', searchValue);
             fetch(url, {
                body: data,
                method: "post"
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.text();
            }).then(function (text) {
                $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
                $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
                $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
                $("#clearone").show();
            });
        };
    });


});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I recommend you just use the jQuery `$.ajax()` functions

Comment: Hey @Phil, as I stated above in my code. I have used `$.ajax` but for some reason it did not work, It gave me an error that `res.test()` not found. If you are saying `$.ajax` works with my code. Can you please show me a working code? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although if you're already using jQuery, it would make sense to use jQuery's built-in request functions like `$.get`, if you want to use `fetch` without changing your code, one option is to simply include a *polyfill* for `fetch`: add the following

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=fetch"></script>
```

(or some other polyfill script which includes Fetch) to your HTML.

Comment: Hey @CertainPerformance thanks for the answer. But, I have a question for you: So, if I put in the beginning of my code in header of my html, and run my code will my web app work in internet explorer 11?

Comment: If the current script works in other browsers, then yes, simply adding a polyfill for `fetch` *should* result in the script working in IE as well (if `fetch` is the only ES6+ feature your script uses)

Comment: Correct. Alright, let me try it and I will let you as soon as possible. If your answer works, you know what will you get. :) Cheers. Thanks.

Comment: One last Question: will this also work in the jquery library `3.3.1` or older jquery libraries?

Comment: If everything in your current script works on other browsers with any version of jQuery, then if `fetch` is the only object you're using that doesn't exist in IE, then the `fetch` polyfill should make the script work too, regardless of the jQuery version

Comment: Great. Thanks. I will let you what will my current state be at soon. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But for some reason the script you provided - did not work. However, after =fetch I added Poly and it works now. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is not supported by Internet Explorer.

For more info on what browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch